# Is there a way to retrieve the SMS id of a student using the Google Classroom API

Tags: google-classroom

We have built an integration with Google Classroom. The get on the user profile returns an id, email, and name for the students given a teacher account.

However, that ID doesn't match up with the school's student management system (the one the school used to get the students into Google Classroom).

I am trying to find out if the school is doing something wrong, or if Google simply doesn't pass this information through.

Comment: Well, I try to get the student number A from two different class with different teacher, and I get the same student number. You can also try it by using the [Method: courses.students.list](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students/list) and pass the courseID of two different class with different teacher.

Comment: The id that comes down with the student appears to be a Google ID of some sort. Most schools rely on their own internal SMS ID to move data between systems. I know G Suite for Education allows the importing of this id via oneroster files (sourceid) but they don't seem to provide a way to retrieve it via the API